# Не обновляется PagedListAdapter после добавления элемента

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть `MainActivity` с `RecyclerView`, в который выводится список из БД через `PagedListAdapter`. Так вот когда я добавляю новый элемент реализуя это в `MainActivity`, то элемент добавляется и сразу же появляется в `RecyclerView`. Но я хочу, чтобы добавление элемента в БД было реализовано в новом `Activity`. А когда из нового активити добавляю элемент в БД, он добавляется, но `RecyclerView` не обновляется (вновь добавленный элемент не отображается в списке), появляется только если перезайти в приложение.

Как сделать так, чтобы он сразу отображался?

```
RusOther

@Entity(tableName = "rusother")
public class RusOther {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String word;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String translation;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int favorites;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    public int getFavorites() {
        return favorites;
    }

    public void setFavorites(int favorites) {
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }

    public RusOther(String word, String translation, int favorites) {
        this.word = word;
        this.translation = translation;
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }

    public static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RusOther> DIFF_CALLBACK =
            new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RusOther>() {
                @Override
                public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull RusOther oldWord,
                                               @NonNull RusOther newWord) {
                    return oldWord.getId() == newWord.getId();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull RusOther oldWord,
                                                  @NonNull RusOther newWord) {
                    return oldWord.equals(newWord);
                }
            };

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        RusOther word = (RusOther)obj;
        return word.getWord().equals(this.getWord())
                && word.getTranslation().equals(this.getTranslation())
                && word.getFavorites() == this.getFavorites();
    }
}
```

RusOtherDao

```
@Dao
public interface RusOtherDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM rusother")
    public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer,RusOther> getAllRusOtherWords();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM rusother where word LIKE  :word")
    public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, RusOther> getAllRusOtherWordsFilters(String word);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM rusother WHERE id = :id")
    RusOther getRusOtherByID(long id);

    //Обновление существующего перевода
    @Update
    int updateItem(RusOther word);

    @Insert
    void insert(RusOther word);

    //Обновление элемента по его ID
    @Query("UPDATE rusother SET favorites = :fav WHERE id = :id")
    void updateItemByID(int fav, int id);
}
```

Adapter

```
public class RusOtherAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<RusOther, RusOtherAdapter.RusOtherHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    private OnItemFavoritesClick favoritesClick;

    public RusOtherAdapter(OnItemFavoritesClick favoritesClick) {
        super(RusOther.DIFF_CALLBACK);
        this.favoritesClick = favoritesClick;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final RusOtherAdapter.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    class RusOtherHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView txtWord;
        private TextView txtTranslation;
        private ImageButton btnFavorites;
        private OnItemFavoritesClick favoritesClick;

        private RusOtherHolder(final View view, OnItemFavoritesClick favoritesClick) {
            super(view);
            txtWord = view.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            txtTranslation = view.findViewById(R.id.txtTranslation);
            btnFavorites = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorites);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            this.favoritesClick = favoritesClick;

            btnFavorites.setOnClickListener(v -> this.favoritesClick.favClick(getAdapterPosition(), getItem(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), getItem(getAdapterPosition()).getFavorites()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(getItem(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            }
        }

        private void bindTo(RusOther word) {
            txtWord.setText(word.getWord());
            txtTranslation.setText(word.getTranslation());

            int fav = word.getFavorites();

            if (fav == 1) {
                btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_yellow);
            } else {
                btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public RusOtherHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new RusOtherHolder(view, favoritesClick);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RusOtherHolder holder, int position) {
        RusOther word = getItem(position);
        if(word != null) {
            holder.bindTo(word);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class AppViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public LiveData<PagedList<RusOther>> rusOtherList;

    public MutableLiveData<String> filterText = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public AppViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public void initRusOther(RusOtherDao rusOtherDao) {
        PagedList.Config pagedListConfig=(new PagedList.Config.Builder()).setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                .setPrefetchDistance(100)
                .setPageSize(50).build();

        rusOtherList = Transformations.switchMap(filterText, input -> {
            if (input == null || input.equals("") || input.equals("%%")) {
                return new LivePagedListBuilder<>(
                        rusOtherDao.getAllRusOtherWords(), pagedListConfig).build();
            } else {
                return new LivePagedListBuilder<>(
                        rusOtherDao.getAllRusOtherWordsFilters(input), pagedListConfig).build();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        RusOtherAdapter.OnItemClickListener, OtherRusAdapter.OnItemClickListener, OnItemFavoritesClick {

    private AppViewModel viewModel;

    private RecyclerView rvList;

    private TextView txtLeftLang;
    private TextView txtRightLang;
    private ImageButton btnChangeLang;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private boolean isOtherRight;

    RusOtherDao rusOtherDao;

    EditText filter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ***

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddActivity.class));
        });

        rvList = findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).getOrientation()));

        rusOtherDao = AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(this).rusOtherDao();

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppViewModel.class);

        initRusOtherAdapter();

        btnChangeLang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                txtRightLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang));
                txtLeftLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang));

                if (isOtherRight) {
                    initRusOtherAdapter();
                } else {
                    initOtherRusAdapter();
                }

                isOtherRight = !isOtherRight;
            }
        });

    }

    public void  insert() {
        final RusOther word = new RusOther("testWord", "testTranslate", 0);
        rusOtherDao.insert(word);
    }

    private void initRusOtherAdapter() {
        RusOtherAdapter adapter = new RusOtherAdapter(this);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        viewModel.initRusOther(rusOtherDao);
        viewModel.rusOtherList.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<RusOther>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagedList<RusOther> rusOthers) {
                adapter.submitList(rusOthers);
            }
        });
        rvList.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewModel.filterText.setValue("");

        filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                viewModel.filterText.setValue("%" + s.toString() + "%");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, id + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

AddActivity

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private EditText txtWord;
    private EditText txtTranslate;
    private Button btnAdd;

    RusOtherDao rusOtherDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        ***

        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(this);
        rusOtherDao = db.rusOtherDao();

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            insert();
            this.finish();
        });
    }

    public void  insert() {
        final RusOther word = new RusOther("testWord", "testTranslate", 0);
        rusOtherDao.insert(word);
    }

}
```

Comment: Мне думается надёжнее и правильнее применить старый добрый `startActivityForResult()` - `AddActivity` возвращает значение, которое нужно добавить, а `insert` выполняется в `onActivityResult()`. Если, конечно, логика работы выглядит как: `MainActivity->AddActivity- >MainActivity`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду в AddActivity в поля вводить нужные данные и передавать их обратно в MainActivity? Я думала можно прям в AddActivity это реализовать, а MainActivity сделать обновление адаптера как-то

Comment: Да, ввод, валидация и передача обратно через result intent. Либо добавить в `AddActivity`, а в `onActivityResult()` принудительно обновить адаптер, сделав запрос в базу.

Comment: Но лучше и менее затратно делать insert в MainActivity значит.. Спасибо, попробую)

Comment: А обновление какого-то элемента тоже по такому же принципу лучше делать?

Comment: Если обновление через другую активность - то, пожалуй да. Тут проблема в том, что подписка цепляется не на базу как файл, а на экземпляр класса, работающего с базой. В другой активности Вы работаете с другим экземпляром и поэтому подписчик не вызывается. Это конечно можно обойти синглтоном, но мы же помним, что Андроид имеет право прибить фоновую активность когда ему вздумается и тогда наш подписчик может снова "проморгать" изменения.

Comment: поняла спасибо)